# iOS IBAction with textDocumetProxy within a second ViewController (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I don't have a ton of experience with iOS development, but I feel like this should be possible. What I'm trying to do is do an IBAction within a second view controller. The IBAction is I'm trying to preform looks like this:

```
- (IBAction)helloWorldButton:(id)sender {
[self.textDocumentProxy insertText:@"Hello World"];
}
```

I've linked up the send event to touch up inside. I am able to pull up the second view controller and properly dismiss it with:

```
- (IBAction)dismissSecondView:(id)sender {
   [[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

}
```

That all works fine which is what's confusing me. Why does the IBAction for dismissing the view controller work but the IBAction for textDocumentProxy doesn't? I can provide more code and information if needed, but I have successfully linked up the two view controllers to appear and be dismissed. I just want a button that types "Hello World" within the secondary view controller.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: ```IBAction``` translates into ```void``` meaning nothing. It is just a placeholder and it has no built in functionality. If a message is marked with ```IBAction``` you can link it to some storyboard element, as you did. That is all. Just to clarify that.

Comment: You can drag from the button directly to the marked message and not worry about specifically linking to touch up inside. That said, add a line in your button function, something like ```NSLog(@"Pushed me");``` just to test that the problem is not (as I suspect) with the way in which you inject the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was thinking about it all wrong. What I was looking to do was change the label on multiple buttons, not change the entire view. What I did was this:

Take the button to change the state of other buttons, and tell it tell it to change the buttons accordingly using

```
- (IBAction)buttonChanger:(id)sender {
if ([_aButton.titleLabel.text  isEqual: @"Hello"]) {
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
    [_anotherButton setTitle:@"World" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_lastButton setTitle:@"Friend!" forState:UIControlStateNormal]; //more buttons after this...
```

Not sure if that example makes a ton of sense (changed the variables up a bit from the original project) but that will change each button accordingly. When I push button "Button Changer", it checks the status of "aButton" to see if anything needs changing, and then changes the title of the other buttons (anotherButton, lastButton) to World and Friend! accordingly. This is exactly what I was looking to do. I realize this is a completely different route to what I was initially thinking, but it works great!

Thanks for your help!